# Import using wildcard in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, import

I wish to take a shapefile export, which is kept in a folder location, and update a sqlite database. My problem is that the shapefile changes name slightly with each and every export.

Is there a way, in the ArcGIS ModelBuilder to handle importing the data with a wildcard?

The export shapefiles are the only ones stored in this folder - would be great if the add data handled Import *.shp.Edit;

Import shapefile, rename shapefile, make feature layer, create feature class based on schema of feature layer, export feature class to SQL database.

[image: model]

Comment: Have you tried to use the iterator for files in a folder?  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-files.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could make the name/path to your shapefile a parameter of your model.
this way each time you run it it will prompt you to enter the curent name/path of your SHP.

The downside is that it's no longer a fully automated task as you need to manually enter information each time you run it.